# android - It is possible to retrieve details from Community posts and each likes at the same time?

Tags: javascript, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'd already done getting the post details. But my problem is I don't know how to get the number of likes and the users who liked the post. Tried many things, but nothing works till now.

The L6r... are the posts.

This is my Data Structure

[image: My Data Structure]

Comment: What post are we talking about?

Comment: @marekful the three L6r... are the posts.

Comment: @marekful or my Data Structure is wrong. is there any other idea to put likes to the Community Posts( L6r... ) and counts who likes the posts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add a single value event on the "like" reference.
Something like:

```
likeReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
     //Do something with snapshot
   }
}
```

Comment: `public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUploads.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    upload.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());
                    mUploads.add(upload);

                }`

Comment: the details from the post are the only thing that I can retrieve. but the like dont

Comment: How does your Upload class look like

Comment: [link](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/andoyrdstuytho-hihihi.appspot.com/o/ask2.png?alt=media&token=84022f45-27cb-464f-8662-f1f11cc3a52f)

Comment: You seem to be missing the "like" child in your Upload class, which is probably why it doesn't parse that data. I think you should first create a class for the Like data structure, and then declare a new like variable in your Upload class.

something like:
`class Upload { Like like; }`
`class Like {int likes; String user_id:}`

Comment: Also you might want to change your data structure

Comment: Thanks @FFGH ! I changed my data structure so i can easily get the number of likes :)